# JXTreeTable: getColumnClass should return different types in base of node

Tags: java, swing, swingx, jxtreetable

I've a `List` of `Profile` objects. `Profile` has a `List` of `User` as its field and I choose to show this information using a `JTreeTable` in `SwingX`.

I have a problem with `getColumnClass(int column)` because this method doesn't distinguish if the node is a parent or a child.
In a nutshell, I would like something like that:

```
//getColumnClass as I expect it
@Override
public Class<?> getColumnClass(Object node, int column) {
   if (node instanceof Profile) {
      switch (column) {ecc.....}
   }
   else {.....}
}
```

Could anyone tell me how to fix this problem. Because I switched to `SwingX` because I thought that a `JTreeTable` could offer more flexible functionalities.

Comment: The class of the column shouldn't matter if it's parent of child, the column class should remain constant...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Ok, but I don't want this. I want that if a row shows a profile, the other columns are Boolean, else if a row shows an user, print his name in the first column and stop. The fact is that if I set Boolean for all columns, even Users have checkBox and this is a problem for me.

Comment: You might look at a custom [renderer & editor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender).

Comment: *"The fact is that if I set Boolean for all columns, even Users have checkBox and this is a problem for me."*: Not if your `getValueAt()` method returns `null` (it would simply display an empty cell)

Comment: It's what I do... getValueAt(...) returns null when node is a instance of User and column>0, but what I get is an empty checkbox